# My Ubuntu 22.04 can not connect to ethernet nor wireless

Tags: networking, network-manager

My Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop is no longer showing the GUI to configure wireless connections and in command line when I run the command ip addr it just shows the loopback address.

When I do `systemctl status NetworkManager` it says that /run/network/ifstate and etc/network/interfaces do not exist

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 in my laptop

Comment: Can I improve my question in anything else?

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484343

Comment: Yes, I asked in Ubuntu forum and here . I thought asking in different sites could help me to resolve faster this issue

Answer (score 0):

I installed ubuntu 22 and had the same issue several times. Each time I removed cloud-init. I installed again, his time I did not remove cloud-init. There was no issues with networking this time.